# Export a Go function from a shared library when a C header file included for cgo also defines it

Tags: go, shared-libraries, cgo, c-header

I'm trying to write a OpenVPN plugin in go. OpenVPN provides a interface as [C header file](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin.ng/blob/7f513adff207ce8efe156a7aecc39359e28ec264/release/src/router/openvpn/include/openvpn-plugin.h).

The header contains a function signature

```
int openvpn_plugin_open_v3(const int version, struct openvpn_plugin_args_open_in const *arguments, struct openvpn_plugin_args_open_return *retptr)
```

which i'm not able to able to implement.

How to create a function in go with the C dereference operator?

I tried

```golang
package main

/*
#define OPENVPN_WRAPPER_H
#include "./openvpn-plugin.h"
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

const OPENVPN_PLUGIN_STRUCTVER_MIN = 5

//export openvpn_plugin_open_v3
func openvpn_plugin_open_v3(
    version C.int,
    arguments *C.struct_openvpn_plugin_args_open_in,
    retptr *C.struct_openvpn_plugin_args_open_return,
) C.int {
    if version < OPENVPN_PLUGIN_STRUCTVER_MIN {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%d: this plugin is incompatible with the running version of OpenVPN\n", OPENVPN_PLUGIN_STRUCTVER_MIN)
        return C.OPENVPN_PLUGIN_FUNC_ERROR
    }

    return C.OPENVPN_PLUGIN_FUNC_SUCCESS
}

func main() {}
```

which results into the following errors:

```
# github.com/jkroepke/openvpn-auth-oauth2/lib
In file included from _cgo_export.c:4:
cgo-gcc-export-header-prolog:49:12: error: conflicting types for 'openvpn_plugin_open_v3'
In file included from openvpn.go:5,
                 from _cgo_export.c:4:
././openvpn-plugin.h:628:44: note: previous declaration of 'openvpn_plugin_open_v3' was here
  628 | OPENVPN_PLUGIN_DEF int OPENVPN_PLUGIN_FUNC(openvpn_plugin_open_v3)
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
././openvpn-plugin.h:184:35: note: in definition of macro 'OPENVPN_PLUGIN_FUNC'
  184 | #define OPENVPN_PLUGIN_FUNC(name) name
      |                                   ^~~~
_cgo_export.c:24:5: error: conflicting types for 'openvpn_plugin_open_v3'
   24 | int openvpn_plugin_open_v3(int version, struct openvpn_plugin_args_open_in* arguments, struct openvpn_plugin_args_open_return* retptr)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from openvpn.go:5,
                 from _cgo_export.c:4:
././openvpn-plugin.h:628:44: note: previous declaration of 'openvpn_plugin_open_v3' was here
  628 | OPENVPN_PLUGIN_DEF int OPENVPN_PLUGIN_FUNC(openvpn_plugin_open_v3)
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
././openvpn-plugin.h:184:35: note: in definition of macro 'OPENVPN_PLUGIN_FUNC'
  184 | #define OPENVPN_PLUGIN_FUNC(name) name
      |                                   ^~~~
```

Comment: It's [really declared](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin.ng/blob/7f513adff207ce8efe156a7aecc39359e28ec264/release/src/router/openvpn/include/openvpn-plugin.h#L606) in that header file, so yes, you have it redeclared. What happens if you rename your Go function to `foo` while keeping the `//export` comment as is? Also note that you don't need `./` in the `#include "..."` directive: the double quotes make the compiler look for the file in the current directory.

Comment: @kostix rename the function in go while leaving the comment results into another error: `./openvpn.go:21:1: export comment has wrong name "openvpn_plugin_open_v3", want "foo"`

Comment: Because cgo creates its headers automatically, you can't implement a predeclared C function via cgo.

Comment: Based on the insight from @JimB, you could try to `#undef openvpn_plugin_open_v3` after `#include`.

Comment: Or name the export something else and call it via a small c wrapper?

Comment: @JimB that approch seems working fine.

Comment: @JimB, care to convert your comment to an answer? I've retitled the question, so your comment would make perfect sense as a proper answer.